# Mysql Windows "mysqldump -t" restore

Tags: mysql, windows, backup, restore

Yes it's Windows sorry.

I'm using mysqldump with the option -T which creates a sql and a txt file per table.

```
mysqldump -u user -ppass db -T path
```

I use that option to be able to restore easily one table.

Now I'd like to restore all the tables.

```
mysql -u user -ppass db < path/*.sql
```

Obvously doesn't work

Also, I don't know where do my funcs/procs go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a FOR loop with the file wildcard (*.sql) to process each one, like this:

```
FOR /R %F in (*.sql) DO (
  mysql -u user -ppass database %F
)
```

(Note that if you're running this from a batch file, the variable should be shown as %%F instead of just %F.)

Comment: this doesn't restore .txt data